# not able to push data into combineddata array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am not able to push data into combineddata array inside the closure function.I found that I need to use the closures for programs related to the database.I am a newbie to node js and javascript.and the async nature of it is making me fall into a lot troubles out like this.Can any one please help how could I deal with this.

```
combineddata=[];
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            (function(){
                x=i;

                teststats.addTestStats.find({Testid:data[x].Testid},function(err,testdata){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                    }else{
                        //console.log(testdata+"no"+x+"yes"+i);
                        console.log(x,i)
                        stat.push(testdata);
                        combineddata.push("examplepush");
                    }

                });
            })();


            }
        }
res.send(combineddata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming with "not able to push" you mean that the `"examplepush"` you push into `combineddata` is not showing in your HTTP response. This is because the database query is executed asyncronously and the pushing code in the callback actually runs after you have already done the `res.send` and returned from the handler.

What you could do is refactor your code so that you only need to execute one query there instead of several queries in a loop, and then you're able to execute res.send from within the database query callback.

Try using something like this as your building block instead of the for-loop:

```
var testIds = data.map(function (elem) { return elem.Testid });
teststats.addTestStats.find({Testid: {$in: testIds}}, function (err, testdata) {
  res.send(testdata) // Testdata is now an array matching all Testid's you queried for
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160209/getting-parent-index-inside-a-custom-directice can you help regarding this